# How to add an object as a property of a JsonObject object?

Tags: java, json, gson

Here is what I am doing:

```
JsonObject jobj = new JsonObject();
jobj.addProperty("name", "great car");
```

I am hoping to add another property whose value is an object as follows:

```
jobj.addProperty("car", A_CAR_OBJECT);
```

But it appears that GSON does not allow me to do `jobj.addProperty("car", A_CAR_OBJECT)`. I am going to eventually do the following:

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(jobj);
```

to get the Json string.

Is this doable? Am I using GSON the right way? Or should I just use a `HashMap` to throw all data into it and then `new Gson().toJson()`?

Comment: A_CAR_OBJECT needs to be a String, number, JsonObject, or JsonArray.

Comment: So, I cannot use Gson to do what I want, correct? Thanks!

Comment: I'm no expert, but as I understand it, you cannot do that directly.  You *can* create a JsonObject containing the values in your object, and add that JsonObject to the overall JSON.  This is what the Jackson-style toolkits do under the covers.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
jobj.add("car", new Gson().toJsonTree(A_CAR_OBJECT));
```

Comment: Strictly speaking this should be jobj.add("car", new Gson().toJsonTree(A_CAR_OBJECT)); addProperty has no overload for JsonElement as a 2nd parameter. Got me there though, thanks!

Comment: why not jobj.add("car", A_CAR_OBJECT); directly?

Comment: Otherwise you'll get your object back as string: `"{}"`