# How to POST JsonObject with Retrofit 2?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

In my app I'm creating a JsonObject

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("command", "session.intSessOK");
            jsonObject.put("appToken", appToken);
            jsonObject.put("aesIv", aesIv2Encrypted);
            jsonObject.put("nextToken", nextToken);
```

putting values in it

```
        byte[] body = Base64.encode(jsonObject.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        AesUtil aesUtil = new AesUtil(aesKeyIv.getKey(), aesKeyIv.getInitVector());
        String finalBody = aesUtil.encrypt(body);
```

converting it to base64 and encrypting it

```
    JSONObject jsonObjectFinal = new JSONObject();
jsonObjectFinal.put("dt", finalBody);
```

finally creating another json object and send the encrypted body as "dt" value

```
 sendInitOk(jsonObjectFinal);
```

And then:

```
private void sendInitOk(JSONObject jsonObject) {

        apiService.generic(jsonObject).enqueue(new Callback<GenericWrapper>() {


            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GenericWrapper> call, Response<GenericWrapper> response) {
                ApiServiceSingleton.getInstance().setHeaders(response.headers());
                Timber.d("INIT SESSION OK: " + response.body().toString());
                try {
                    Aes aes = new Aes();
                    ApiServiceSingleton apiSingleton = ApiServiceSingleton.getInstance();
                    byte[] dataBytes = Base64.decode(response.body().getDt(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                    byte[] data = aes.decrypt(apiSingleton.getIv().getBytes("UTF-8"), apiSingleton.getKey().getBytes(), dataBytes);
                    String dataString = new String(data);
                    Timber.d(dataString);

                } catch (Exception ignored) {
                    ignored.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GenericWrapper> call, Throwable t) {
                Timber.e("INIT SESSION OK ERROR" + t.getMessage());
            }

        });


    }
```

Api service:

```
@POST("getRequest")
    Call<GenericWrapper> generic(@Body JSONObject jsonObject);
```

GenericWrapper class in kotlin:

```
class GenericWrapper {

    @SerializedName("dt")
    @Expose
    var dt: String? = null

}
```

There is no error in client side but I'm not getting a response.

Backend side gets the json value as `NameValuePairs = { "dt" = "......."`

instead of `"dt" = ...`

**edit: so I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28406481/6683139) and switched to Gson's JsonObject but this time I'm getting a BadPaddingException. Strange NameValuePairs thing dissepeared thpough**

Comment: Have a look at [This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43853436/retrofit-2-how-to-pass-a-post-json-object).

Comment: @ADM please see my edit

Comment: changing `apiService.generic(jsonObject)` to `apiService.generic(jsonObject.toString())` and then ``@Body JSONObject jsonObject` to `@Field JSONObject jsonObject` should work

Comment: don't you need value for @Field ?